# OS X installation error

Tags: ros, macosx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
when i try to run " ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"
the install failed with the following error "library not found for -ltinyxml".
i already install tinyxml using brew and tried to reinstall but with same result.
Thank

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193719/os-x-installation-error/) by [borisbr](https://answers.ros.org/users/20337/borisbr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I received this error when it came to **image_transport** from **image_common**. What you can do, if it is image_transport that throws the error, is to edit the CMakeList.txt in ros_catkin_ws/src/image_common/image_transport and remove the line with tinyxml

```
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} sensor_msgs_gencpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
#  tinyxml
)
```

See these two links from the issue tracker

- https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common/issues/28
- https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common/commit/b756d8187ed71a2dde9e14f78898ec448dcd47c0

---

Originally posted by [tropic](https://answers.ros.org/users/3186/tropic/) with karma: 84 on 2014-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0